# How to create a bottom up listview in javafx?

Tags: java, javafx

some use case like a list of messages that must items added to top of list need have a reversed list view. because of :

suppuse we have a listview with 20 items in it. when add 10 items in the top of list with `listItems.addAll(0, newItems)  ;` javafx call updateItem 30 times because 20 old items indexes changed. and this maybe need more cpu usage if list items have a huge ui.

Comment: I guess you're making a mountain out of a molehill. 30 `updateItem` calls shouldn't be expensive unless you're doing expensive stuff in the `updateItem` method itself. In that case however caching could help...

Comment: @fabian it's just example. in some case i have +1000 items in listview.

Answer (score 1):

`updateItem` is called for visible cells only. It doesn't matter how many items there are in the list. There should be no real benefit in creating a bottom-up `ListView` for this purpose (which will probably require you to reimplement the listview skin...).

You can check this with the following code:

```
int counter = 0;

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    ListView<Integer> listview = new ListView<>();
    listview.setCellFactory(lv -> new ListCell<Integer>() {

        @Override
        protected void updateItem(Integer item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            System.out.println("called "+ ++counter);
            setText(item == null ? "" : item.toString());
        }

    });
    listview.getItems().addAll(IntStream.range(0, 10000).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList()));
    VBox.setVgrow(listview, Priority.ALWAYS);

    VBox root = new VBox();
    Button button = new Button("add");
    button.setOnAction(evt -> {
        System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------");
        listview.getItems().addAll(0, IntStream.range(listview.getItems().size(), listview.getItems().size()+20).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList()));
    });
    root.getChildren().addAll(listview, button);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

For me that's 40 `updateItem` calls for the initialisation of the `ListView` and `54` for the list modification. This does not change whether there are 20 or 10000 items initially (about 17 cells are shown when I test the program).

Comment: can u help me to re implement  listview skin to bottom up behavior ?